Where can I get a list of chemicals uploaded to NIST Chemistry WebBook?
While there are many software programs (e.g., R's webchem) that can query properties of a specific chemical, is there a place to get a list of available chemicals with which I can query the database?
This post covers the case for PubChem and the original poster alludes to a NCBI query that essentially gives results for the NIST Chemistry WebBook, but their links are dead.
Thanks in advance.

NIST does not offer bulk downloads of their data, for free.  But, they do sell access to various datasets.  It's difficult to tell exactly what datasets are compiled together in the Chemistry WebBook, but here are some databases that include thermochemical data for chemicals, some of which is probably in Webbook:

ThermoML/Data Archive.  Has data from 2003 to 2019 from five major journals in the field of chemistry and chemical engineering thermochemical properties data.
NIST-Janaf Thermochemical Tables.  Has data free energies, entropies, enthalpies, etc. for "48 elements and many of their compounds."

You might be able to learn more about whether bulk downloads or local installations of the WebBook are available for purchase by contacting NIST.

Didn't realize they sold their data - but contacting them directly is probably the best move.

I think one of the issues is that it's not all "their" data; e.g. license agreements with the journals and/or researchers that originally published it may make things complicated.
